# Iterate over the Json object to fetch level 3 data in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, foreach, iteration

I m trying to loop over the below json object to fetch "x-visibility": "Public
The selected output needs to be written in a new json file.

I m trying to use ForEach-Object  on  "paths",how do I iterate over  "/about" and etc and fetch "x-visibility" object ?

```html
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Ope sepc  API",
    "version": "20.8.0"
  },
  "basePath": "/qrs",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/about": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "65d540ef-b3b9-4678-ae24-2d8abdc304cc",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/About"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-visibility": "Public",
        "x-stability": "Locked"
      }
    },
    "/about/api/default": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "3d1a3502-a020-4a37-8da3-90b7e030792e",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "listentries",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "default": true,
            "type": "boolean",
            "allowEmptyValue": true
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          }
        }
  ]
    }
  }
}
        "x-visibility": "Private",
        "x-stability": "Locked"
      }
    },
    "/about/api/default/analyticconnection": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "2b781738-afd0-37a9-4248-84ec8d6be58c",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "listentries",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "default": true,
            "type": "boolean",
            "allowEmptyValue": true
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/AnalyticConnection"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-visibility": "Public",
        "x-stability": "Locked"
      }
    },
    "/about/api/default/app": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "f868fb6f-330f-60f8-0851-60eadf848788",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "listentries",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "default": true,
            "type": "boolean",
            "allowEmptyValue": true
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/App"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-visibility": "Private",
        "x-sability": "Locked"
      }
    },
    "/about/api/default/app/content": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "4d486f37-c652-85bb-c291-a7384cccdfad",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "listentries",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "default": true,
            "type": "boolean",
            "allowEmptyValue": true
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/AppContent"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-visibility": "Public",
        "x-stability": "Locked"
      }
    },
```

I have to do all this in powershell and I m not to the world of powershell scripting.
Please help if possbile

Comment: This doesn't look to be valid json. Can you double check your code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix your JSON. The following should do what you want:

```
 foreach ($p in $data.paths.psobject.properties.value) { $p.get }
```

`PSObject.Properties` will give you a list of all of the properties on an object.

Comment: Doesn't that imply a prior `$data = Get-Content -Raw -Path jsonFile.json | ConvertFrom-Json` OP might be looking for?

Comment: It is not only get ,some properties may have more than one  property value  ,Like some may have Get ,Some may have Get,post.So how do I accomodate this ?